# Why does unpacking a record that has a key containing bounded data fail with `to_value sp.TBounded` in smartpy?

Tags: smartpy, error, testing, types, pack

Tests are throwing a `to_value` error in the scenario when trying to unpack a record that contains a key with a bounded type `TNat` inside the entrypoint being called.

There's a minimal reproduction below, and a link to the SmartPy IDE at the bottom.

Example Contract:

```
import smartpy as sp

test_type = sp.TRecord(
    num=sp.TNat,
    select=sp.TBounded([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], sp.TNat),
)

class PackUnpackBoundedTypes(sp.Contract):
    def __init__(self):
        self.init(
            rec = sp.pack(
                sp.record(
                    num=sp.nat(2),
                    select=sp.bounded(5)
                )
            ),
            done = sp.record(
                num=sp.nat(1),
                select=sp.bounded(1)
            )
        )
        
    @sp.entry_point()
    def get_unpacked_info(self):
        res = sp.unpack(self.data.rec, test_type).open_some()
        self.data.done = res
```

Contract Tests:

```
@sp.add_test(name = "PackUnpackBoundedTypes")
def test():
    scenario = sp.test_scenario()
    scenario.h1("PackUnpackBoundedTypes")
    alice = sp.test_account('alice')
    
    c = PackUnpackBoundedTypes()
    scenario += c

    c.get_unpacked_info().run(sender=alice)
```

Failure:

```
Error: Error in Scenario
Unexpected error in transaction, please use .run(valid=False, ..)
Failure: to_value sp.TBounded([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], t=sp.TNat) 5;
get_unpacked_info
```

[SmartyPy IDE Link](https://smartpy.io/ide?code=eJx1UsFOAyEQvfMVxEshEpKt9mKyidG7MaaejCEIs7qxCwTYQ_9eYGntdts5EJh5b@bNMP3grI84DNJHt8cy4OAQihCiiHsHuE1vvn0DZb0mCCcz49Bm34uMrDgC7EDF4nuyo9GgyUfD8JrhO4bvGd58MlwJlCGKkNrJEPCrVL_vxqWzsrapXiAJ@WxN9FJF@lDya@iwEL3poxAkFeuqv9bueA6RoyubBzUpz@nnocJy3J90dG61QyMjWVN2EfLf81dteUMXwLnnLJO2pk73mpQTGc0FGUsJzVlBtLyVy2PiQBrxXjjbm0jocczfEMVY_gR0mnhnz@ftIUyiJ1QJcy2jzF0wfNwbyq0DI4IdgND5bxV07T6lQyjLkVqLTCZGDjlwc3k7bijKMguyqgoKjPS9nWQVAQdXrXx48p@GXM@bkXLXKzhJJJVKoEhWJbCaQOXI63VlgedF8W2LFZo4fDleyv1o0hQT3belCv0D_6IAFQ--)

Is it not possible to pack/unpack bounded types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unsafe without a dynamic check.
We need to determine what the most natural and/or appropriate decision is (very possibly: continue forbidding it).

Comment: can the docs please be updated with details on what types are packable/unpackable, maybe a warning on each type page, as well as an overview table on the pack/unpack part of the documentation